# How to extend a class with functions based on data and checked at compile time?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I have some classes with methods that are generated by data. These classes are available to a user, and I want type checking at class instantiation time. So if a user doesn't implement these classes correctly, an error occurs at class construction time. That is, I want to write a higher order function that extends a class' signature and marks those methods as abstract.

So, using regular code, the implementation would look like this:

```
from abc import abstractmethod
class A():
  @abstractmethod
  def process_init(arg):
    pass
```

and the user class

```
class B(A):
  def process_init(arg):
    print(arg)
```

Easy. Except in my case 'init' is actually data, and could be a long list of atoms. Now, code generation to a file is ugly in python 3. So I want to do something like:

```
class A():
    def dummy(arg):
        pass

    for i in ['init', 'start', 'pause', 'stop']:
        name = 'process_' + i
        setattr(A, name, dummy)
        make_abstract_method(A, name)
```

such that the following will object when B is instantiated because the abstract method has no implementation

```
from a import A
class B(A):
    pass
B()
```

What is the magic incantation for `make_abstract_method`? (I want a instantiation time error, not a runtime error or exception, so having dummy execute raise `NotImplementedError` doesn't work here.)

Comment: sorry, I hear "compile" and "python" in one sentence?  Shortly - python is interpreter, you can't achieve anything at "compile" time

Comment: @Reishin well, that's just simply not true. Running code with CPython involves a compilation phase to bytecode, and that bytecode is run on a bytecode interpreter. Just like Java. So, one example of something that happens at compile time is the tagging of variables that are local. For example, `x = 2; def f(): if False: x = 1; print(x)` will throw an unbound local error, even though the assignment statement is not reachable by the interpreter, and that's because the *compiler* sees the assignment statement and marks `x` as local

Comment: @Reishin OK, then explain how the interpreter throws an UnboundLocal error. Or what the `compile` function does (hint: it compiles source code to byte code).

Comment: Python is not compiled.  Your question/demand is nonsense.  Choose a language that supports compilation if that's what you want.  Python is strongly typed, but dynamically typed.

Comment: In *any case* Python does no type checking at compile time. Types are dynamically resolved - Python is a dynamic language. You *can* however probably achieve something that happens when your program starts and class definitions are executed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga pyc files you referring is a JIT bytecode, which is still translated by cpython. Same as pyc stage exists only for optimization of performance and could be skipped.

Comment: Sure, but *every* time you run a Python program you are executing *compiled* bytecode, that can be cached as a pyc file, but it doesn't have to be, but that doesn't mean *there isn't a compilation of the source code to byte code at some point*. You cannot skip this compilation phase, because the interpreter cannot execute source code directly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you can, just pass "-B" as argument

Comment: @Reishin no, that isn't what `-B` does. That simply prevents *caching the results* of the compilation as a `.pyc` file. But the *whole source code* is still compiled into bytecode, kept in memory, and that bytecode is executed by the interpreter. And *yes* there are various things that happen at compile time, e.g. the marking of local variables, and various minor, peep-hole optimizations (e.g. constant folding), the caching of various immutable literals, etc etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it called JIT compiling, it is not the same as compiling and you cant compile and link the code in the same way you doing it for Java, C, C++ or any other pure-compiled language. Please distinguish it.

Comment: I never claimed that CPython is purely compiled. I've been very precise in my claims, and I never said any of that. In any case, I don't think generally you would use the term JIT compilation for what CPython does, it has more in common with the AOT compilation done in your typical bytecode-compiled system. Generally, in that, JIT compilation refers to the compilation of bytecode to machine code, as done by the Java runtime, or by PyPy (another Python implementation)

Comment: I'm trying to show that cpython compilation is a part of translation which you can't separate, with possibility to cache some steps to pyc for speed up at next launch. 

The truth is that python didn't have any definition as "abstract" and "compiler" have no idea about it.  Instead, better treat python as purely interpreted language and use LINTER instead

Comment: edited question to change compile time to class instantiation time to clarify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good way to accomplish exactly what you want using `abc`. `abc` is quite limited in Python. And fundamentally, it requires that the `abstractmethod`s should be marked when the class object is instantiated. So, you *could*  rely on the undefined behavior of modifying `locals()` in the class definition statement:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def dummy(arg):
        pass

    for i in ['init', 'start', 'pause', 'stop']:
        name = 'process_' + i
        locals()[name] = abstractmethod(dummy)
```

Where, ideally, you'd like to be able to do:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta
class A(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def dummy(arg):
        pass

for i in ['init', 'start', 'pause', 'stop']:
    name = 'process_' + i
    setattr(A, name, abstractmethod(A.dummy))
```

But then the abstractmethods will not be enforced.

Likely, you'd be better off calling the the `type` constructor directly (in this case, of course, of the `type` subclass `ABCMeta`):

```
A = ABCMeta(
    'A',
    (object,),
    {
        f"process_{i}": abstractmethod(dummy)
        for i in ['init', 'start', 'pause', 'stop']
    }
)
```

And of course, you cannot accomplish any of this at *compile* time, which for Python just does translation from source code to byte code, with minor optimizations, with no type-checking.

Now, it will throw a runtime error if you try to instantiate a `B` object:

```
class B(A):
    pass

B() # TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods dummy, process_init, process_pause, process_start, process_stop
```

But `abc` won't complain at class definition time (which is the best you could hope for anyway).

You could write a custom metaclass to accomplish this at class definition time.

Comment: wrong..use build system and python lint as step between the goal

Comment: @Reishin yes, using third-party static analysis would be a valid solution, but I'm not sure how that will handle the dynamic attributes. If you have a fleshed out answer, by all means, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: This answer is very clear complete and thanks for the work. (And reading past the original post use of compile time instead of instantiation time)